# scrollView with UIImage respond touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm using a simple code to add some images to my `UIScrollView`. Also I've implemented another code to detect touches on each image.

Here is the code:

```
(void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    int senderTagIs;

    senderTagIs = sender.view.tag;

    if (sender.view.layer.borderColor != [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor) {

        sender.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor;

        UIImageView *showFullImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.view.tag+100];
        [showFullImage setTag:sender.view.tag+200];
        [self.view addSubview:showFullImage];
        showFullImage.hidden = NO;

        NSLog(@"Show tag is: %i", sender.view.tag);

    }
    else
    {
        sender.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

        UIImageView *hideFullImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.view.tag+200];
        [hideFullImage setTag:sender.view.tag+100];
        hideFullImage.hidden = YES;

        NSLog(@"Hide tag is: %i", sender.view.tag);
    }

}
```

The above code, sets the border color to cyan and show my small images from `UIScrollView`, in another `UIImageView`.

But my problem is, that I can't set the option to hide all images and set border color white for all images when one image is touched.

Ex: If I touch the first image, then the code will work, my big UIImageView will show touched image and touched image from `UIScrollView` will get the cyan color for border, so far so good.

Now, If I touch third image, my first image is shown, the color border is cyan, and so... I have to touch first image again to disable, but this is not what I want.

Comment: you have dynamic or static images?and you have every time the same number of images in your scrollView?

Comment: yes, everytime the same number of images. static images.

Comment: ok so I have a easy solution for that

Answer (score 0):

So, we've got a few things going on here.  First, I'm assuming you're trying to show a collection of images in a scroll view with some custom padding to indicate selection around them.  This sounds tailor make for using UICollectionView with a custom cell.

Absent further information, you're not resetting the old color.  Either keep a reference to a selected image as a class variable or, assuming your image views are in a collection object like an NSArray, begin your method by iterating through the objects and resetting their view to an unselected state.

If you just need to hack together a solution, the second option should work.  I really recommend using UICollectionView.  It's a bit more work in the beginning, especially if you're not experienced with it, but it's well worth learning.  Here's a good tutorial on [UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12).